# Android sub menu with actionLayout is not visible

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to display custom sub-menu item.
Menu is inflated and menu items are created. But sub-menu that was created with `android:actionLayout` is empty/blank.

I'm using ActionBarSherlock 4.3.

What am I missing here?

This is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/action_bar_overflow_icon"
        android:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_view_reserve"
                android:actionLayout="@layout/item_edit_reserve"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_view_delete"
                android:icon="@drawable/item_manage_icon_delete"
                android:title="Delete"
                />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

This is my layout/item_edit_reserve.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/item_manage_icon_reserved"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Reserve"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Inflating:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.item_edit, menu);
}
```

Comment: Since a sub-menu is not supposed to be displayed until its menu is selected, I would expect that you cannot put a sub-menu item into the action bar via things like `actionLayout`.

Comment: Then why sub-menu is inflated and while debugging action view is visible and has children which also are visible?

Comment: First, you say that it is "empty/blank". Then you say it is "visible". There appears to be a conflict in your testimony.

Comment: While debugging view.getVisibility() is VISIBLE. By empty/blank I mean this http://i.imgur.com/HwXP8AF.png.

Comment: And my point is that I have no idea why you think `actionLayout` works on sub-menus.

Comment: Because I haven't found where it says that it shouldn't :) Do I have any alternatives then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31724/discussion-between-martynas-jurkus-and-commonsware)

Comment: So what are the alternatives for this?

Comment: @osrl I did not found a solution at that point and then dropped the feature altogether and didn't get a chance to get back to the problem.

Comment: thanks @MartynasJurkus. I ended up using `PopupWindow`