# Is it possible to create custom view for ActionBar SubMenu?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I want to create ActionBar sub-menu item with custom layout or view.

Something like: `ImageView - TextView - ImageView`

It is possible to create MenuItem with custom layout or view, but I wasn't able to achieve that with sub-menu - 
[Android sub menu with actionLayout is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088920/android-sub-menu-with-actionlayout-is-not-visible)